# Problem using laplacian in a problem.

Tags: functions

**QUESTION**: Consider a triangle $PQR$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $A$ be a point lying on or inside $\Delta PQR$. PT: for any function $f(x,y) = ax + by + c$ on $\mathbb R^2$, $f(A) \le max(f(P),f(Q),f(R))$.

**MY ATTEMPT**: I started by observing that $\nabla^2 f(x,y) = 0$. This means that $f(x,y)$ satisfies the Laplace equation. Thus, all extremum must occur at the boundary. So I know that $\exists T(x',y') | f(A) \le f(x',y')$ where $T(x',y')$ is a point of the boundary of the triangle. Thats as far as i got. Can someone help me prove that the $T(x',y') \in [P,Q,R]$? Any hints would be appreciated. I would prefer to finish the problem on my own. Please do not post solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Remark: All extremum must occur at the boundary is not a true statement. Instead, it should be there exists an extremum that occur at the vertex or the boundary (actually we know that we can find one at the vertex). For example, we can let $a=b=0$ and hence $f(x,y)=c$ everywhere.

Suppose $T(x'.y') = \lambda P + (1-\lambda) Q$ where $, \lambda \in (0,1)$, $f(T(x',y'))=f^*$ and $f^*$ is the optimal vallue.

If we have $f(P) < f^*$ and $f(Q)<f^*$, we should arrive at a contradiction.